# delay showing and hiding rows from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display a table with 100 rows and I want to show the first 20 rows and hide the others at first..and after that the next 20 rows until we reached 100 rows and refresh the page...I'm using setTimeout function to delay the process to hide and show specific rows but if I use setTimeout with 26000 seconds it doesn't respond

> PHP

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY jloc_title ASC) AS Rownum,jloc_id, jloc_title 
FROM Locations";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connection,$sql);
if($stmt == false)
{
echo"Error (sqlsrv_query):".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true);
exit;
}
while($row1=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
{
$id = $row1[0];
$title = $row1[1];
$Rownumber = $row1[2];              
echo"<tr id='Row' value='".$Rownumber."'    >";
echo"<td class='text-center'> " .$Rownumber.  "</td>";
echo"<td class='text-center'> " .$id. "</td>";
echo"<td class='text-center'> " .$title. "</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
?>
```

> jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var number = document.getElementById("table1").rows.length ; 
alert (number); 
    $(function(){
        $("#table1 tr").each(function(){
            var val = $("td:eq(0)", this).html();
            if(val > 2)
            {
                $(this).hide(); 

                        setTimeout(function(){  
                        $("#table1 tr").each(function(){
                        var val1 = $("td:eq(0)",this).html();
                        if(val1 <= 2)
                        {$(this).hide();    }
                        });
                        },13000);


                        setTimeout(function(){          
                            $("#table1 tr").each(function(){
                            var val2 = $("td:eq(0)",this).html();
                            if( 2< val2 && val2 <= 4)
                            {
                                $(this).show();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                setTimeout(function(){location.reload();}, 13001);
                            }
                        });
                        },13001);

                if(number > 4 )
                {

                        setTimeout(function(){  
                            $("#table1 tr").each(function(){
                            var val3 = $("td:eq(0)",this).html();
                                if( val3 <= 4)
                                {
                                $(this).hide();
                                }
                            });
                        },20000);
                                    setTimeout(function(){          
                                    $("#table1 tr").each(function(){
                                    var val4 = $("td:eq(0)",this).html();
                                        if( val4 > 4 && val4 <= 6  )
                                        {
                                            $(this).show();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},20001);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    },20001);

                                if(number >6 )
                                {
                                    setTimeout(function(){   
                                    $("#table1 tr").each(function(){
                                    var val5 = $("td:eq(0)",this).html();
                                    if( val5 <= 6 )
                                    {
                                        $(this).hide();
                                    }
                                    });
                                    },26000);


                                    setTimeout(function(){   
                                        $("#table1 tr").each(function(){
                                        var val6 = $("td:eq(0)",this).html();
                                        if ( val6 > 6 && val6 <= 8 )
                                        {
                                            $(this).show();


                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},26001);
                                        }

                                        });
                                    },26001);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},25003); 
                                }

                }
                else
                {
                    setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},25000); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},20003); 
            }
        });
    });
```

});

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

### Intro

I had some difficulty understanding your script. 
I thought to make a different script that does the same thing.

The script below hides all the rows.

It then goes through every second and makes 20 new rows appear.

A fix in the final version would be to avoid global parameters. (working on it)

Example Scriptlet: https://jsfiddle.net/qs193r20/1/

```
<script>
var i= 0;
var limit = 100;
var a = function(){

                                    var list = $("#table1 tr");
                                    i=i+20;
                                    alert(i);

                                    $("#table1 tr").each(function(){
                                        var val = $("td:eq(0)", this).html();   
                                        if(val < i){
                                             $(this).show();
                                        }
                                    }); 

                                    if(i < limit){
                                        setTimeout(a, 1000);
                                    }


                                 };


$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Test1");

var number = document.getElementById("table1").rows.length ; 
alert (number); 
    $(function(){

        //Hide All
        $("#table1 tr").each(function(){
                var val = $("td:eq(0)", this).html();   
                $(this).hide();             
        }); 





         setTimeout(a, 1000);



        }); 

});     

</script>
```

Comment: the problem is that i want to display first the 20 rows for 13 secs after that hide those 20 rows ( 0-20 ) and display 20-40 for 13 secs...and sow on until we finally get 100 rows and refresh the entire page and read the whole table again to check for new rows

Comment: @Legend Whirlwind  " and refresh the entire page and read the whole table again to check for new rows" ... so once you have gone through the 100 items, you want to reload the entire page? 

I can modify my script to do what you want... just trying to understand the full thing. So you wanna show only 20 rows at a time.. and after 5 times, reload the entire page? ( 5 * 20 rows = 100 rows... refresh, do again)

Comment: first of all thank you for your help mate... the whole story is this...i have a table with exams and students and i want to display the results to a monitor that refreshing the results...in the begging i want to read the entire table and showing the first 20 students and pausing for a while...after that the program hides the first 20 students and it will show the next 20 and pause...until we reach the last student and in the end we will refresh the entire page to check if we have a new student